# Django Url TypeError

Tags: python, django

when I surf to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/getEmail/getMyMessages/
```

I have the following error:

```
getMyMessages() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

myapplication/urls.py includes:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^getEmail/', include('get_new_emails.urls')),
```

I have an app named 'get_new_emails' and get_new_emails/urls.py includes:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
    url(r'getMyMessages', views.getMyMessages)
)
```

from get_new_emails/views.py:

```
def getMyMessages():


    from django_mailbox.models import Message

    qs = Message.objects.all()
    count = 0
    for i in qs:
        count += 1
        output = output + str(count)+ " " + i.text +'<br>' + '<br>'

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you paste your views?

Comment: here is the relevant view function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the request parameter of your function:

```
def getMyMessages(request):


    from django_mailbox.models import Message

    qs = Message.objects.all()
    count = 0
    for i in qs:
        count += 1
        output = output + str(count)+ " " + i.text +'<br>' + '<br>'

    return HttpResponse(output)
```